# HID callback function - linux equivalent?

Tags: linux, usb, hid

I have a HID phone monitor that comes with windows DLLs. I want to port this to linux.

The software relies on a callback function to report events.

Given that there is no support for Linux with this device Im having to rely on low level APIs like libusb and hidapi for communication. Im not clear on how I would implement an event callback using either of these.

Would it be a nonblocking read? Something similar?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blocking read, as long as it's on a dedicated file descriptor, should be fine. Then the application can use `select()` (or a suitable abstraction on top) to wait for events in parallel with waiting for other events on other descriptors.

It seems [libusb](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__poll.html) has plenty of support for handling both sync and async reading from the device.

Comment: i'll give it a shot. getting the communication working is going to be a big hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

HID devices are exposed under /dev/input already, presumably yours generates key events.  Broadly you find your device using lsusb or traversing sysfs, open /dev/input/eventN (or maybe one of the by-id or by-path links udev creates) to get a file decriptor, and read out events.  See `Documentation/input/input.txt` in the kernel tree for docs on the interface.  It's very simple.

It's hard to give you more specific advice without more information about your device.